# MacPro 1,1 video's card

Tags: mac, graphics-card

I just bought a Mac Pro 1,1 from my coworkers and I'm looking to upgrade video card as the one inside is very noisy.

What are my options? Basically I'm not looking to spend a lot of money, in fact i'd rather to spend as little as possible and get low end or mid range card, I'm not really playing games all that much so pretty much anything will do, I'd prefer 2xx series though. Current Mac Pro sells w/ GT120, Apple sells upgrade kit for $149 (which is okay, I just not sure if I'll be able to use this card on such an old Mac Pro)

Comment: Super User is not a shopping site, so the budgetary/pricing parts of your question are not really on topic.  however i think the technical part of this question make it worth keeping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There aren't a lot of options for the first Mac Pro.

There's the ATI X1900XT, NVIDIA 7300GT and the newer ATI Radeon 4870. For what it's worth the Radeon 4870 is near whisper quiet in a newer Mac Pro.

The newer NVIDIA cards do **not** work with the original Mac Pro. The original Mac Pro (MacPro 1,1) requires a 32-bit EFI firmware on the card. [Source](http://store.apple.com/us/question/answers/product/TW387ZM/A?mco=MTQzNTExNjk&pqid=QAAFD4K4U4AJ4F4JP9PHDJPAF2CFDJ9DC)

Answer (score 1):

From [Final Cut Pro X, Motion 5, Compressor 4: Graphics card compatibility](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4664):

> The following AMD, ATI and NVIDIA graphics cards support OpenCL in Mac
>   OS X v10.6 Snow Leopard and in OS X Lion:
>
> NVIDIA
>
> - GeForce 320M
> - GeForce GT 330M
> - GeForce 9400M
> - GeForce 9600M GT
> - GeForce 8600M GT Note: OpenCL compatible, but does not meet system requirements for Final Cut Pro X, Motion 5 and Compressor.
> - GeForce GT 120 GeForce GT 130 GeForce GTX 285 GeForce 8800 GT GeForce 8800 GS Quadro FX 4800 Quadro - FX5600
>
> ATI
>
> - Radeon HD 4670
> - Radeon HD 4850
> - Radeon HD 4870
> - Radeon HD 5670
> - Radeon HD 5750
> - Radeon HD 5770
> - Radeon HD 5870
>
> AMD
>
> - Radeon HD 6750M
> - Radeon HD 6630M
> - Radeon HD 6770M
> - Radeon HD 6970M

Comment: I am using an ATI HD4650 PC card in my Mac Pro 1,1 with upgraded xeon 5345 processors (now 8core instead of 4). Apart from a couple of unhappy games, all is stable and well.  You do not get the grey apple boot up screen but I can live with that. Long live Mac Hacking!!

Comment: Next time please cite your source and quote it properly. Also watch your formatting, the lists ended up as one big paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of replacing the card, it might be possible to replace the fan. I silenced a noisy X800 by getting a passive cooler made by Zalman. I don't know what GPU is in your computer, but if it's a stock ATI or Nvidia you should be able to find a cooler upgrade kit.